# Network visualization issue

Tags: r, plot, graph, igraph, networkd3

I have a rather [large dataset](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=75236117563938170103) with two columns `from`, `to` . I am trying to produce a simple network diagram to visualize the relationship between various elements in these two columns so I tried this simple example below.

```
Source <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
Target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
NetworkData <- data.frame(Source, Target)

library(networkD3)
simpleNetwork(NetworkData,linkColour="yellow")
```

The only difference between the example above and my dataset is that I have `1500` rows/observations in [my dataset](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=75236117563938170103). However the `simpleNetwork` function is producing a giant sunflower type visualization of the various associations and this is not very pleasant.

[Network Graph Output][2]

My question is 1) Is there a better way to visualize this data 2) How can I at least color the target nodes differently from the source nodes ?

Any advise or suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect an insightful visualization for this dataset to be? I mean, from a quick glance, there seems to be only connections from/to node `435.9`, which thus get's the "center of the universe"

Answer (score 1):

To answer generally, to **the first part of the question**, different visualisations may be meaningful depending on what you're trying to illustrate. Try to get some basic descriptives for the network: Edge-count, density, avg. path distance, and you've already come far in knowing what kind of relational data you're looking at. As lukeA pointed out above, insightfulness in graph visualisation are very dependent on the structure of the network data at hand!

Visualisations don't have to be meaningless, but I would conceder to use them rather to prove a pedagogical point than to actually derive any analysis from them, you should think first of what you want to visualize in the grpah.

When you have decided what would give the desired insight, colouring the nodes are a key visual tool indeed:
As for **the second part of the question**, in `networkD3` you should use the `NodeGroup` argument to colour nodes. In igraph you assign a vector to  `V(graph)$color`, and in the sna-package to the argument `vertex.col` when plotting using `gplot()`.

Here's your example graph coloured by distance from A in igraph:

```
Source <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
Target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
NetworkData <- data.frame(Source, Target)

# Visualize using igraph
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(NetworkData), directed = TRUE)

# Colour by distance from first node:
heatmap <- colorRampPalette(c("red", "yellow"))(100)
distance.from.first.node <- distances(g, V(g)[1])
V(g)$color <- heatmap[1+round(distance.from.first.node / (max(distance.from.first.node)/(length(heatmap)-1)))]

# Plot
plot.igraph(g)
```

I can not think of any points to make out of plotting the data you provided, but if you need to, here it is:

```
# Get the data you downloaded vvv(MAKE YOUR OWN PATH HERE)vvv
data <- read.csv(file="Downloads/Network.txt", sep="|")
# Remove your missing data
data <- data[data[,1]!="",]
data <- data[data[,2]!="",]
g2 <- graph_from_edgelist(as.matrix(data), directed = TRUE)

# Re-colour and plot:
distance.from.first.node <- distances(g2, V(g2)[1])
V(g2)$color <- heatmap[1+round(distance.from.first.node / (max(distance.from.first.node)/(length(heatmap)-1)))]

# Plot with smaller vertexes and no labels
plot.igraph(g2, vertex.size=4, vertex.label=NA)
```